# Multiple excel files and multiple sheets to a single excel file but with different excel sheets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

firstly I ask admin not to close the topic. Because last time I opened and it was closed that there are similar topics. But those are not same. Thanks in advance.

Every day I receive **15-20** excel files with huge number of worksheets (**more than 200**). Fortunately worksheet names and counts are same for all excel files. I want to merge all excel files into one but with multiple worksheets. I am new in Python, actually I watched and read a lot about the options how to do but could not find a way. Thanks for your support.

**example I tried:** I have two files with two sheets (actual sheet count is huge as mentioned above), I want to merge both files into one with two sheets as *sum.xlsx*.

*Data1.xlsx
Data1.xlsx*
***sum.xlsx***

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir(r'C:\Python\db')  # we open the folder where files are located
os.chdir(r'C:\Python\db')  # we change working direction

df = pd.DataFrame()  # we create an empty data frame

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Python\db\Data1.xlsx')  # we load one of file to extract list of sheet names
sh_name = wb.sheetnames   # we extract list of names into a list


for i in sh_name:
    for f in files:
        data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=i)
        df = df.append(data)
        df.to_excel('sum.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name=i)
```

Comment: What is the error/issue with your code?

Comment: It does not give the result what I need. It seems I cannot write correct code.

Comment: *It does not give the result what I need.* Can you be more specific? What you can see after running your code?

Comment: It creates sum.xlsx file, but with only one sheet and appends all data inside it from Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: Try to empty your `df = pd.DataFrame()` after `df.to_excel(...`?

Comment: Thanks for feedback, **Shaik**. Do you mean, should I empty **DataFrame** after **df.to_excel()** ? But the purpose is not to merge all data in the same worksheet. The purpose is: if the worksheet name is same then I want to merge/append data and go next worksheet to do the same action. Here I think it removes the first sheet once it goes to the next and append all in a worksheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208616/discussion-between-shaik-moeed-and-markhor).